# jquery unwrap Inner

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a simple inline edit for a div box. When i dblclick on the div, i wrapInner with textarea tag. That makes it editable. But how can i unwrap the textarea tag when i click outsite the textarea field. Below is what i have which is not working. Also Should i use focusout, mouseout, mouseleave or any of them.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<div id="test" style="width:300px; height:200px;">
    testing
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#test").live({
    dblclick: function() {
        $("#test").wrapInner("<textarea/>")
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $("#test > textarea").unwrap()
    } 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things you should probably do differently.

```
$("#test").dblclick( function() {
    $(this).wrapInner("<textarea/>").find('textarea').focus();
}).delegate('textarea','blur',function() {
    $(this).parent().text( this.value );
});
```

- Bind the `dblclick` directly to `#test`
- In the `dblclick` handler `.find()` the new `textarea`, and `.focus()` on it
- Place a `.delegate()` handler on `#test` instead of using `.live()`
- Use `blur` instead of `mouseleave`
- In the `blur` handler, set the `.text()` of `#test` to the `value` of the `textarea`. (This is important in order to pick up the edits that were made.)

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/drQkp/1/

---

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/drQkp/2/

Here's an example that allows HTML to be typed into the textarea.

```
$("#test").dblclick(function() {
    $(this).html($("<textarea/>",{html:this.innerHTML})).find('textarea').focus();
}).delegate('textarea', 'blur', function() {
    $(this).parent().html(this.value);
});
```

Comment: That works, but When you are already inside the text area and you dblclick again, text disappears. It's creating another instance on textarea with every dblclick.

Comment: After testing this out, it doesn't do the work on unwrap. it's really removing every child tag inside and not just textarea. If We have a span tag wrapped around a word, then span tag will be removed.

Comment: @alex: are you talking about tags that were typed into the textarea? [Here's an updated example.](http://jsfiddle.net/drQkp/2/) It allows HTML, and doesn't use any `wrap` type of methods.

Comment: Yes almost there. I meant if the div container already contains span tags or other html. In your case user will see html code when editing. I don't want to show html source. I want to edit text just as in your first example, but retain it's already existing html properties. More like a editor preview mode and not source mode. check http://jsfiddle.net/alex00/uXteF/1/

Comment: @alex: So, you want the new textarea to contain only the text without any HTML tags that may have been present, but you want to retain those tags when editing is complete. Unfortunately this would be extremely difficult to achieve. Once the tags have been removed, you'd need to remember the old content *with* the tags, analyze the new text that has been now edited, then place the tags back in at the appropriate points, which could be impossible to determine. Perhaps you're looking for a javascript based text editor [like this one](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php)?

Comment: Thanks, i came to the same conclusion after much research on this subject.

Comment: @alex: Sorry I couldn't have better news for you. Best of luck. :o)

Answer (score 17):

`$("#test > textarea").unwrap()` is unwrapping the textarea, therefore removing the div #test, rather than removing the textarea. Instead you want:

```
$("#test > textarea").contents().unwrap()
```

As you can see from this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RJ6kZ/), the mouseleave will trigger immediately on any mouse movement after the `wrapInner`, so you probably want to bind the mouseleave to the textarea inside the doubleclick handler.

Answer (score 0):

Unwrap doesn't exist as far as I know. Once you have `$('#test > textarea')`, assign its contents to its parent.

It would be a lot less error-prone if you started off with the text "testing" inside a `<span>` or something, then copy the span's contents to a textarea, then back again.

Comment: @alex Oops! However, it works on DOM elements, not their value contents.